# Unexpected Symbol for Project

Tags: c#, for-loop

I'm having some trouble understanding why "unexpected symbol" exists for my code. I'm using for loops for a project and these few lines of code are giving me problems. I'm guessing it has something to do with not putting brackets/ semi-colins somewhere, but I don't know where it would be. Could I get some help identifying where I need to correct this error?
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maIJC.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7LWm.png)

Here's the full code where the errors exist

```
 // Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    string[] imagesNames = new string[3] { "portrait01", "portrait02", "portrait03" };
    //images [0] = CreateSprite ("portrait01");
    //images[1] = CreateSprite ("portrait02");
    //images[2] = CreateSprite ("portrait03");
    string[] professionNames = new string[3] {"Karate fighter", "Ninja Figher", "Samurai Fighter"};
    string[] professionDescriptions = new string[3] { "Use hand to hand combat for powerful attacks! Req: Strength = 13 and Special = 10", 
        "Use high stealth and sneak attacks to suprize you enemies! Req: Speed = 15 or Strength = 9", 
        "Use your wisdom to reverse attacks with 2x the power! Req: Wisdom = 14 or Special = 13" };

    string[] professionImageNames = new string[3] { "profession01", "profession02", "profession03"};
    int[] [] minRequirements = { new int [3] {11, 11, 12}, new int[3] {11,13,12}, new int[3] {11,11,16} };




professions = new Profession[3]
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)

    {
        professions[i] = CreateProfession (name[i], description[i], profimages[i], minRequirements[i]);

    }


    for (int i = 0; i < professionNames.Length; i++) //this starts at least one of the loops

    {
        profession[i] = createItem(professionNames[i], professionDescriptions[i], professionImageNames[i], minRequirements[i]);

    }


    //profession01 = createItem("Karate Fighter", "Use hand to hand combat for powerful attacks!", "portrait01");
    //profession02 = createItem("Ninja Fighter", "Use high stealth and sneak attacks to suprize you enemies!", "portrait02");
    //profession03 = createItem("Samurai Fighter", "Use your wisdom to reverse attacks with 2x the power!", "portrait03"); 


    for (int i = 0; i < imagesNames.Length; i++) //creates a for loop for the images
    {
        images[i] = CreateSprite(imagesNames[i]); //makes it so the images come from CreatSprite
        //array     
    }

     portraitImage.sprite = images[currentImage]; //renders the current images


profession.characterManager = this;

for (in i = 0; i < minRequirement.Length; i++) {

    profession.requirements [i] = profession.CreateRequirement { Attribute [i], minRequirement[i];
}

return profession;

}
```

Comment: For a start, this `professions = new Profession[3]` needs a `;`

Comment: Also, your last for loop is missing the "t" in "int i = 0;"

Comment: your variables  name are not consistent

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `;` on this line:

```
professions = new Profession[3]
```

These types of errors should be pretty apparent, usually you always want to inspect the line *above* the first error, missing a semi-colon is probably the most common programming "error", and it was a lot worse before IDE's highlighted error lines.

The second error, as pointed out by Lazy Coder, is a missing `t` on the last for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < minRequirement.Length; i++)
```

Again, should be apparent from reviewing the errors. It should be giving an error *"Identifier expected; 'in' is a keyword"*

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    string[] imagesNames = new string[3] { "portrait01", "portrait02", "portrait03" };
    //images [0] = CreateSprite ("portrait01");
    //images[1] = CreateSprite ("portrait02");
    //images[2] = CreateSprite ("portrait03");
    string[] professionNames = new string[3] {"Karate fighter", "Ninja Figher", "Samurai Fighter"};
    string[] professionDescriptions = new string[3] { "Use hand to hand combat for powerful attacks! Req: Strength = 13 and Special = 10", 
        "Use high stealth and sneak attacks to suprize you enemies! Req: Speed = 15 or Strength = 9", 
        "Use your wisdom to reverse attacks with 2x the power! Req: Wisdom = 14 or Special = 13" };

    string[] professionImageNames = new string[3] { "profession01", "profession02", "profession03"};
    int[] [] minRequirements = { new int [3] {11, 11, 12}, new int[3] {11,13,12}, new int[3] {11,11,16} };




professions = new Profession[3]  //WERE IS THE PROFESSION CLASS CREATED?
//PROFESSIONS NEEDS TO HAVE A TYPE var profession = new Proffession[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)

    {
        professions[i] = CreateProfession (name[i], description[i], profimages[i], minRequirements[i]); //CreateProffession is not implemented on your example, the signature could be like public Profession CreateProfession(string name, string description des, string proofImage, int[] minRequirement)

    }


    for (int i = 0; i < professionNames.Length; i++) //this starts at least one of the loops

    {
        //DID YOU MEAN professions
        profession[i] = createItem(professionNames[i], professionDescriptions[i], professionImageNames[i], minRequirements[i]);

    }


    //profession01 = createItem("Karate Fighter", "Use hand to hand combat for powerful attacks!", "portrait01");
    //profession02 = createItem("Ninja Fighter", "Use high stealth and sneak attacks to suprize you enemies!", "portrait02");
    //profession03 = createItem("Samurai Fighter", "Use your wisdom to reverse attacks with 2x the power!", "portrait03"); 


    for (int i = 0; i < imagesNames.Length; i++) //creates a for loop for the images
    {
        //DID YOU MEAN imagesNames
        images[i] = CreateSprite(imagesNames[i]); //makes it so the images come from CreatSprite
        //array     
    }

     portraitImage.sprite = images[currentImage]; //renders the current images  //WHERE IS currentImage created?


profession.characterManager = this;

//FOR is for(int i=0 , int with t
for (in i = 0; i < minRequirement.Length; i++) {

    profession.requirements [i] = profession.CreateRequirement { Attribute [i], minRequirement[i];
}

return profession;

}
```